# Clearing celery back-end result data

Tags: django, python-3.x, celery

I have a django project with celery library integrated. How can I clear my celery back-end result data?

I am using `django-db` as my celery worker backend.

```py
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django-db'
```

Comment: This question asks something similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13147581/celery-task-clean-up-with-db-backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Task **expire** kwarg and periodically call **cleanup** database backend method or try to use **forget** method of AsyncResult after every result completion.